# VFS lock files are not removed after processing

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are using WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. We have developed a proxy for reading a CSV file and inserting into a database table. File is configured to be MOVED to a history folder after processing. When the file is dropped in the FTP folder, a lock file would be created. It normally will be removed when the processing is over. But now it never gets deleted and the lock file stays as it is in the input folder. We couldn't find out the reason for the same. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: can you find errors in wso2-esb-errors.log ?

Comment: we couldnt find any specific errors. but few places we saw a FTP connection timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to set transport.vfs.Locking parameter to disable creation of a .lock file when its processed.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a known error in ESB 4.8.1. There is a patch available from WSO2 support, but that requires having a support contract. You can also use a newer version of the ESB since 4.8.1 is already quite dated, using 4.9 or 5.0 you should not run into these problems anymore.

Comment: I personally prefer 5.0. It has been out for a while already.